# make.com - ringcentral api not returning any calls

Tags: make.com

So I have to get rincentral calls (caller, callee, etc) into a database but for some reason the ringcentral api isn't returning anything. any tips or things i am clearly doing wrong?

here is my current config.

```
[img1](`https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA6GF.png`)
[img2](`https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNiir.png`)
[img3](`https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjNn6.png`)
[img4](`https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsqPM.png`)
```

I don't know what else to try I would expect this to just work considering it is a low-code/no-code solution. and it should just return a list of 1000 calls that were made.